# Python - get text between HTML tags

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Below you can see my code. It runs through a list of projects and gives a table as an output.

```
x = PrettyTable(["Soli", "Zusammenfassung", "Bearbeiter", "Status", "Termin"])

display = Display()
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.example.com')

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

 for j in range(0,len(total_tickets)):
            url = driver.current_url
            r = requests.get(url)
            html_content = r.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')

            ticket = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='ghx-issues-in-epic-table']/tbody/tr/td[2]/a")
            ticket[j].click()

            driver.get_screenshot_as_file("test.png")
            worker = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='peopledetails']/li/dl[1]/dd").find_element_by_class_name("user-hover").get_attribute("rel")
            Soli = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='key-val']").get_attribute("data-issue-key")
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='summary-val']/span").click()
            conclusion = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='summary']").get_attribute("value")
            status = soup.find('span',{'class':'classname'}).get_text
            try:
                termin = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='datesmodule']").find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='customfield_10090-val']/span[1]/time").get_attribute("datetime")
            except NoSuchElementException:
                termin = "No Deadline"

            x.add_row([Soli, conclusion, worker, status, termin])
            x.padding_width = 1
            with open('file', 'w') as w:
                w.write(str(x))
```

First Problem, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "save.py", line 104, in <module>
status = soup.find('span',{'class':'classname'}).get_text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

if i delete the "get_text" attribute the status part always shows "NONE" as output.

This is the HTML where it should get the text. I want that it shows me the text "NEU" between the span-tag.

```
<li class="item item-right">
    <div class="wrap">
        <strong class="name">
            Status:
        </strong>
        <span id="status-val" class="value">
            <span class="classname" original-title="">
                Neu
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="status-view">(<a href="#" class="classname">Arbeitsablauf anzeigen</a>)
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Maybe because the `span` is not in the top level of the document but rather nested? By the way it can be accessed fairly easily via `xpath`.

Comment: you should use `driver.page_source` instead of using `requests.get()`. `requests` could get different data than `Selenium` if it doesn't use correct headers.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the select method in beautifulsoup

```
soup.select("div#id")[0].text
```

[0] means the first element

"#id" is the id of the div

.class is the class of the div

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `get_text` - you need to call it, [it's a method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
soup.find('span',{'class':'classname'}).get_text()
```

A more robust and reliable way to "translate" this BeautifulSoup locator to Selenium would be a *CSS selector*, not an XPath - XPath does not, for one,  have any handling of multi-valued attributes like [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.classname").text
```

Or, there is also a direct "by class name" technique:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("classname").text
```

Answer (score -1):

GOT IT :)

just had to change

```
status = soup.find('span',{'class':'classname'}).get_text
```

to

```
status = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").text
```

Comment: Specify the `xpath` as well.